# socket.io websocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Console in browser prints me this messege when I connect with server. I'm still able to emit events from server side and cach them on client side, but i am unable to emit them from client side.

**Server side:**

```
var express    = require('express');
var http       = require('http');
var app        = express();
var server     = http.createServer(app);
var io         = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

 app.get("/", function(req, res) {

        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

    });


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
             console.log(data);
        });
```

**Client side:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id ="id">TUTAJ JESTEM</h1>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
    <script>

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });

window.onload=socket;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you doing window.onload=socket ?

Comment: I thought this might fix the prblem but it didnt. i was desperated.

Comment: Ah. You have a similar problem to mine, although I'm just using WebSocket (not express or socket.io): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429510/cannot-find-an-answer-to-fix-issue-with-websocket-connection-closing?noredirect=1#comment70065129_41429510