# Cannot find an answer to fix issue with Websocket connection closing

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

### Struggling with one issue on a simple Websockets example using node

I originally used this [Websocket/node tutorial](http://codular.com/node-web-sockets) as a starting-point. This is my first attempt, so I knew almost nothing when I started.

"Connection closed before… handshake" is a very common issue, to which there seems to be no definitive answer. From the many SO questions I've spent a day trying answers and suggested code, to no effect, including checking my proxy and allowing localhost (no joy).

Here's my code, including an (incomplete) front-end (I used `npm install websocket` in my local dir, not using socket.io, and although I'm willing to try I'd rather get this working first):

#### server.js

```js
"use strict";

let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {});
const PORT=8080; 

fs.readFile('client/index.html', function (err, html) {
  if (err) throw err;    
  http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html);  
    response.end();  
    console.log(`${(new Date())} Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
  }).listen(PORT);
});

let WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

let wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(r){
  // runs on connection
  let connection = r.accept('echo-protocol', r.origin);
  let count = 0;
  let clients = {};
  // Specific id for this client & increment count
  let id = count++;
  // Stores the connection method for looping through & contacting all clients
  clients[id] = connection;

  console.log(`${(new Date())} Connection accepted [${id}]`);
  connection.on('message', function(message) {

    // The string message sent to us
    let msgString = message.utf8Data;

    // Loops through all clients
    for(let i in clients){
      // Sends a message to the client with the message
      clients[i].sendUTF(msgString);
    }
  });
  connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
    delete clients[id];
    console.log(`${(new Date())} Peer ${connection.remoteAddress} disconnected.`);
  });
});
```

#### index.html

```html
<body>

  <h1>Hello Web Sockets</h1>
  <div id="chatlog"></div>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage()">
  <!-- lose 'onclick' later -->

  <script>
    "use strict";

    let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080', 'echo-protocol');

    function sendMessage(){
      console.log(ws);
      let message = document.getElementById('message').value;
      console.log(message);
      ws.send(message);
    }

    ws.addEventListener('message', function(e){
      // The data is the message being sent back
      let msg = e.data;
      // Append the message to the DOM
      document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML += `<br>${msg}`;
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What is `.utf8Data`?

Comment: Apart from the descriptive name, I don't know, but presume it's the way the WebSocket node module that handles UTF-8 in this context (as in the example here): https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node